# PostgreSQL and Hibernate: Found: numeric, expected: int8

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have table in PostgreSQL which contains column with type `numeric(20)`.

I have mapped this column on field of type `Long`.

While validation part hibernate gives me an exception, saying: `Found: numeric, expected: int8`. I can not change type of column in the database, how to solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `columnDefinition` into the column annotation:

```
@Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "NUMERIC", length = 20)
```